# Looping through xpath variables

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop, webdriver

How can I increment the Xpath variable value in a loop in python for a selenium webdriver script ?

```
search_result1 = sel.find_element_by_xpath("//a[not((//div[contains(@class,'s')]//div[contains(@class,'kv')]//cite)[1])]|((//div[contains(@class,'s')]//div[contains(@class,'kv')]//cite)[1])").text

search_result2 = sel.find_element_by_xpath("//a[not((//div[contains(@class,'s')]//div[contains(@class,'kv')]//cite)[2])]|((//div[contains(@class,'s')]//div[contains(@class,'kv')]//cite)[2])").text

search_result3 = sel.find_element_by_xpath("//a[not((//div[contains(@class,'s')]//div[contains(@class,'kv')]//cite)[3])]|((//div[contains(@class,'s')]//div[contains(@class,'kv')]//cite)[3])").text
```

Answer (score 0):

why dont you create a list for storing search results similar to

```
search_results=[]
for i in range(1,11) #I am assuming 10 results in a page so you can set your own range
    result=sel.find_element_by_xpath("//a[not((//div[contains(@class,'s')]//div[contains(@class,'kv')]//cite)[%s])]|((//div[contains(@class,'s')]//div[contains(@class,'kv')]//cite)[%s])"%(i,i)).text
    search_results.append(result)
```

this sample code will create list of 10 values of results. you can get idea from this code to write your own. its just matter of automating task.

so
`search_results[0]` will give you first search result
`search_results[1]` will give you second search results
...
...
`search_results[9]` will give you 10th search result

Comment: @user3627283: if my answer helped you then you can up vote my answer and mark accepted answer :)

Comment: Unfortunately, Vote Up requires 15 reputation

Answer (score 0):

@Alok Singh Mahor, I don't like hardcoding ranges. Guess, better approach is to iterate through the list of webelements:

```
search_results=[]
result_elements = sel.find_elements_by_xpath("//not/indexed/xpath/for/any/search/result")

for element in result_elements:
    search_result = element.text
    search_results.append(search_result)
```

Comment: that was just sample code. because I was not aware about his exact requirement. I even dont know what HTML code which he was parsing. so that code was just a hint that its possible to loop :)